# How do I offset a view in an HStack but still constrain the frame to match with the offset?

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, layout

As the title suggests, I'm looking to offset some views, a `Circle` inside of an `HStack`, however in doing so, this results in weird behavior where the frame of the HStack is no longer properly wrapping the contents. I need this "Offset" action to still allow proper leading and trailing padding, without empty space there. I considered using a `ZStack` as well, however I feel like that might be cumbersome as I need it to "Wrap" my contents, rather than take all space available.

[image]

```swift
HStack {
    ForEach(novaraUsers.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        let user = novaraUsers[index]
        
        if index < visibleUserCount + 1 {
            Group {
                if index < visibleUserCount {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .stroke(Color.getRandomColor(from: user.username), lineWidth: 4)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .overlay(
                            Text(user.username.prefix(1))
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.h1)
                        )
                } else {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .stroke(Color.getRandomColor(from: String(novaraUsers.count)), lineWidth: 4)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .overlay(
                            Text("\(moreThanCount)+")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.h1)
                        )
                }
            }
            .offset(x: CGFloat(offsetPerCircle * index) * -1)
        }
    }
}
.frame(width: CGFloat(50 * (visibleUserCount + moreThanCount)))
.border(.black, width: 2)
```

Comment: Don’t offset the first circle and work off that or use SwiftUI.Layout which would handle this very gracefully.

Comment: Ooh I'll look into Swift Layout. That might be just the thing I'm looking for. I did find a super hacky solution however, that does work, but I'd prefer the right way lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this layout is to switch the way the circles are drawn. Instead of having a circle as the base view with the text as an overlay, use the text as the base view and apply the circle as background. If the circle is slightly larger than the base view (the text) then you get the overlap effect you are after and no offset needs to be used at all.

Like this:

```swift
Group {
    if index < visibleUserCount {
        Text(user.username.prefix(1))
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.h1)
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
            .background {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .stroke(Color.getRandomColor(from: user.username), lineWidth: 4)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            }
    } else {
        Text("\(moreThanCount)+")
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.h1)
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
            .background {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.white)
                    .stroke(Color.getRandomColor(from: String(novaraUsers.count)), lineWidth: 4)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            }
    }
}
// Not needed
//.offset(x: CGFloat(offsetPerCircle * index) * -1)
```

[image: Players]

Comment: This... has to be... one of the cleverest solutions I've ever laid eyes on. Bravo!

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for accepting it after you already found a solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to offset the HStack after offsetting the `Circle()` in the HStack.

```swift
    var totalOffset: CGFloat {
        var offset = 0
        for index in 0 ..< visibleUserCount + 1 {
            offset += offsetPerCircle * index
        }
        return CGFloat(offset)
    }
```

And then adding the modifier to the `HStack`

```swift
HStack {
   //Content
}
.offset(x: totalOffset / CGFloat((visibleUserCount + 1)))
```